# Empty cookie Passport for Chrome

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, cookies, passport.js

I deployed a MERN app on render.com , after a successful login I see a blank page instead of a dashboard on chrome. Firefox works perfectly fine. After spending some time troubleshooting, I came to the conclusion that this could be a passport cookie authentification issue.

This is the code for the login page :

```
  const login = (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("user" + loginUsername);
    console.log("mdp" + loginPassword);
    Axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        username: loginUsername,
        password: loginPassword,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "https://docuptest.onrender.com/auth/consultantLog",

      
    }).then((res)  => res.data !='No User Exists' ? navigate ('/homepage-consultant/' + res.data._id) : null );
 
  };
```

If succesfuly authentificated, redirect to homepage-consultant that fetch data like this :

```
export default function HomepageCons() {

    const [data, setData] = useState();

 
useEffect(() => {
    Axios ({
       method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
        url: "https://docuptest.onrender.com/auth/consultantLog",
 
     
      }).then((res) => {
       setData(res.data || {});       
      });
 }, []) 

 console.log("dats is " + JSON.stringify(data))
```

That data **is always empty** on chrome. When I look at the server side code of the route :

```
router.post("/consultantLog", async (req, res, next) => {

  passport.authenticate("consultant", (err, user, info) => {
   
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.send("No User Exists");
    if (!user) console.log("No user found");
    else {
    
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
   
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log("this is your user from passeport " + req.user)
        res.send(req.user);
       
       
      });
  
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
 
  res.send(req.user); // The req.user stores the entire user that has been authenticated inside of it.
  console.log('I get this  ' + JSON.stringify(req.user));
});
```

req.user is undefined. When I type 'document.cookie' in the console on 'homepage-consultant', it shows an empty string which mean the cookie is not set

Middleware is set up like this :

```
var app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://docup.onrender.com", "https://docup.onrender.com/homepage-consultant/652328d07dac59e782a1ad58"],// <-- location of the react app were connecting to
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(express.json());
app.use("/documents", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/documents")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);


app.use(cookieParser("secretcode"));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./passportConfig")(passport);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://docup.onrender.com'); // Replace with your front-end URL
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();


});

module.exports = app;
```

Any idea on how to retrieve that data on google chrome ?